# Allow accessing a files only from specific generated URL in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

I have an issue with 'woocommerce upload' folder because it has a .htaccess with "Deny from all" so that no-one can access the contents of the directory through a browser.

However I want to allow access to the custom download link that woocommerce generated whenever a virtual product has been purchased. Is there a way I can allow access for a specific URL? that came from `www.mydomain.com/download_file=xxx&email=&key=xxx`?

Thank you!